# I can't find "Restrict where this project can be run" in the configure page

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I use Jenkins,I can't find "Restrict where this project can be run" in the configure page,should I add some plugins? which one?

Answer (score 20):

This is because you have not yet added any new nodes to your Jenkins set up. Till then the master(where you have installed Jenkins) is the only available machine where jobs can be run. So there is no need to ask where the job needs to be restricted to be run.

Check [this link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) to see how to add a new node to your jenkins setup. Once you add a new node, you will see the option of "Restrict where this project can be run".

Comment: @Shiva Kumar any idea how can I bind a pipeline project to a slave node ?

Answer (score 8):

This is because you have not added any **label** to your master node (if you don't have slaves).

This is a bit weird because you could also use the node name (i.e. 'master') to restrict the executor node, not only the label, and you may want to do this before you add further slaves.

Comment: Yep. If you label your master node "master", "Restrict where this project can be run" will not be available. Solution: label your master node "master_node" and voila, your jobs will now have that checkbox visible.

Answer (score 4):

"Restrict where this project can be run" exists only for Freestyle and other classic project types, for Pipeline you should use node(label) steps within your Pipeline definition